# remove hyperlinks from the selected li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove all hyperlinks from the selected li with jquery but doesn't seems to work properly. When is clicked all my hyperlinks getting removed. A detaliet view of my code http://jsfiddle.net/78kAu/1/. The event what is firing the code looks as it follows

```
    $('a').click(function(){
        var selected = $(this).attr('class');
        var row = $('.elements li').length;
        alert(selected);
        $("a").remove();

        });
```

Comment: To get the class of the clicked element, you should use `this.className` or, if you must go through jQuery, `$(this).prop('className')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("a").remove();
```

you want:

```
$(this).remove();
```

What you've got says "find all the `<a>` elements on the page, and remove each of them."

If you want to remove all the `<a>` elements from some container above the clicked element, like an `<li>`, you'd do this:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('a').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback what I want to remove all ('a') from the current li

Comment: $(this).closest('ul#elements').hide() is doing the job what I wanted so accepted